# Representation of a bounded linear operator $T: c \to c$.

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem, summability-theory

Let $T: c\to c$ be a bounded linear operator, where $c$ is the vector space of convergent real sequences. How can we prove that there exists an infinite matrix $A=(a_{n,k}: n,k\ge 1)$ such that $T(x)=Ax$ for all $x \in c$?

The proof is very easy replacing $c$ in both places with $c_0=\{x \in c: \lim_n x_n=0\}$ (indeed, in such case, $\{e^i: i\ge 1\}$ is a Schauder basis for $c_0$, where $e^i \in c$ is the sequence which is constantly equal to $0$, except $e_i^i=1$).

Comment: You sure such a matrix always exists?

Comment: It should be: it is written in Maddox's book "Elements of Functional Analysis", p. 164 with a remark of the type "slightly more care is needed in describing mappings from $c$."

Comment: I suppose you mean the remark saying: "Using methods similar to that of Theorem 2 it can be shown that for certain sequences spaces $X$, $Y$, every $A\in B(X,Y)$ is given by a matrix." (Followed by enumeration of possible pairs of $X$ and $Y$.) I guess that it is good to mention also in the post (rather than only in a comment) where the claim was taken from.

Comment: Indeed, I was meaning that part. Thank you Martin

Comment: Apparently there is a newer edition of this book. However, I was not able to access pages [214](https://books.google.sk/books?id=ZZk4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA214) and [215](https://books.google.sk/books?id=ZZk4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA215) in Google Books. (Judging from what I was able to see, the part about matrix transformations should start around there in the other edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "$Ax$".

If you consider the standard definition ma matrix multiplication (ie. with respect to the "basis" $\{e^i: i\ge 1\}$) it does not hold. Consider for example the operator $T$ defined by
$$T(x) = (\lim x_n, 0, 0 ,\dots).$$
Then $T:c \rightarrow c$ is a bounded linear operator but cannot be expressed by a matrix multiplication as the limit does not depend on any finite initial segment of a sequence. In a certain way, this is the only operator on $c$ which can't be expressed by matrix multiplication, see below.

However, the space $c$ can be identified with $c_0 \oplus \mathbb{C}$ via identification $(x_n) \leftrightarrow ((x_n - \lim x_k), \lim x_k)$. Hence it has a Schauder basis $(u, e^1,e^2, \dots)$, where $u = (1,1,1,\dots)$, and every bounded linear operator $T:c \rightarrow c$ can be expressed by matrix multiplication with respect to this basis.

Comment: I agree with everything you wrote. So, it seems there is a mistake in Maddox's book..

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets Your $T$ is just the counterexample I was having in mind. You did a good job here. ;-)